# PHP require_once above the root

Tags: php

This is probably a very simple query, but I'm confused by the PHP require_once operation.

I have a website, lets call it www.mysite.com, running on an IIS server in the folder `c:\websites\mysite.com\wwwroot\`

In my www.mysite.com/index.php, I require_once an includes.php which sits in a folder called common - so `require_once("../common/includes.php");`

Within this includes.php is a require_once to my database connection file - which lives above the root - in `c:\websites\mysite.com\`
So, in `includes.php`, I `require_once("dbase_connection.php");`

In each folder of the server, I have a file called `dbase_connection.php` which has 1 line - `require_once("../dbase_connection.php");`

This works...

Now, I'm setting up a simple CMS in a folder called 'admin'. In the www.mysite.com/admin/index.php, I also require_once the `require_once("../common/includes.php")`. Fine so far...

In theory, if I'm in the `\admin\index.php`, then requiring `dbase_connection.php` should go up the directory structure until it finds the final `dbase_connection.php` which has the connection string - but it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

A better query might be, what's the best/proper way to include database connection strings in a procedural php site?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The path for nested `require_once()` is always evaluated relative to the called / first file containing `require_once()`. So this is why it does not work for you. To fix this you have to specify the relative path starting from the file where you first call `require_once()`.

You can also maintain the `include_path` in your *php.ini* or use `set_include_path()`, [see documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php).

Answer (score 0):

You should try making one config.php file that you include in each file, that is in a defined path. Inside it you should define some constants for the paths of your app's DB connection:

```
define('DBINCLUDE', '/path/to/include/db.php');
```

Then in all your files just:

```
require_once(DBINCLUDE);
```

You can do the same for your functions and commons. You can make the paths either hardcoded or with the help of `_FILE_`, `$_SERVER`, `getcwd()` which would work great if you plan to move your codebase to other boxes.

Also, it's a good idea to make your DB connection once withs its params and all and use it across all your app, but you might find that later on in your development path. Usually, there's a `connect_db();` or `MyDB::Connect()` that you can always call after you `require` or `include` your DB file.

Hope that helps.

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php and

Comment: Thanks for the responses - I'll use this method. I was hoping to be able to use my includes file to do all the require_once requests in 1 place (rather than repeat the code on each page)...